# How to disable TextBox if it not empty By JavaScript on page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have an asp.net page that contain some textbox in ListView 
I want to disable textbox that have some text by asp.net ItemDataBound ListView Event or Javascript code
How can i do that?

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server"  DataKeyNames="ID" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="xl68" height="29" style='mso-height-source: userset; height: 21.75pt'>

        <td >&nbsp; <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Visible="false" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label></td>
        <td class="xl66" style='border-top: none'><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %> </td>
        <td class="xl69" width="351" style='border-top: none; border-left: none; width: 263pt'> <%# Eval("Name") %></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="2" Text='<%# Bind("C1") %>' ID="txb1"  ></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="2" Text='<%# Bind("C2") %>' ID="txb2"  ></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="2" Text='<%# Bind("C3") %>' ID="txb3"  ></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="2" Text='<%# Bind("C4") %>' ID="txb4"  ></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td><asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="2" Text='<%# Bind("C5") %>' ID="txb5"  ></asp:TextBox></td>
        <td class="xl67">&nbsp;</td>

        </tr>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it in CodeBehind by this code in Page_Load Event

```
foreach (ListViewItem row in ListView1.Items)
                    {
                        foreach (Control txt in row.Controls)
                        {
                            if (txt is TextBox)
                            {
                                if (((TextBox)txt).Text != "")
                                    ((TextBox)txt).Enabled = false;
                            }
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

add the CssClass property with every TextBox control like this

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" MaxLength="2" ID="txb1" CssClass="myCss"  ></asp:TextBox>
```

add the Js function in aspx

```
 function DisableInput(){

     var inputs = $('input.myCss[type="text"]');
     inputs.each(function( index ) 
     {
       if( $( this ).text() !='')
       {
        $( this ).attr('disabled',true);
       }
     });

 }
```

**On you Page_Load event add this code**

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:DisableInput(); ", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

On you `Page_Load` event add this code

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript:disablewithText(); ", true);
```

In that javaScript function you can iterate through all the textboxes and check for having value and accordingly you can set disable attribute.